# Can we create bash instance in perl script?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use Perl to create a process running bash and then create a file `sample.txt`, but after the bash command I can't see any output on the console or any `sample.txt` file in the same directory structure. Can somebody help me to fix following code?

```
my $var = `bash -l`;
system($var);
print "Done!";

my $filename = 'sample.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
chmod(0777, "sample.txt");
print $fh "hello";
close $fh;
print "Done 1!..";
```

Comment: Did you mean to write: `my $var = "bash -l";` so that the `system` would execute `bash -l`, rather than the output of `bash -l`?  As it stands, you are running the `bash -l` as a command with Perl capturing the output (so you won't ever see it on the screen).

Comment: No.This is what I wants to write my $var=`bash -l`;But here question is why I cant see any output?And what if I wants to see?Any suggestion.

Comment: You mean you really want ``my $var = `bash -l`;`` which means that you will not see the output from the login shell until the `system` statement tries to execute the prompts etc as commands?  I think you are confused.

Comment: Well my main purpose is to see output and execute all statements after bash -l command.I have tried both the ways " " and `` both are not displaying anything on console.

Comment: as @dlamblin  mention below bash -c means logout? I tried this one and its working...

Comment: You can refer to the bash man page about what -l and -c means. I think it means "here's a command string." You should also read the first part of the man perlop I/O operators page about why the backticks weren't working for you: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators

Comment: Thanks all..I guess i have got whatever I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash's `-l` argument is convincing it to stay interactive. Running:

```
perl -e 'print `bash -l`'
```

On its own has the bash process bound to stdin interactively, but the subprocess's output is captured by perl and printed later when bash exits, which it will only do when you press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, issue `exit` or `logout` etc.

You probably wanted to start with `$var = 'bash -l';`. That will start bash interactively at first, and when you exit, will continue the remainder of the program. To me it's unusual to *want* to do this and I expect you should write something for bash that exits normally, probably with the `-c` argument.

Replacing your first two lines of code with:

```
 system("bash", "-c", "echo Hello World!");
```

accomplishes this and the remainder of the program executes normally. I'm unsure what you wanted bash to do for you however. These example cases would be better accomplished with just
`system("echo", "Hello World!")` or `print "Hello World!"`.

Comment: Changing the assignment to `my $var = "bash -l";` (single or double quotes work the same in this context) let's it work correctly.  The `system` function runs the process with standard input, output, error all connected to Perl's standard channels, and the shell works sensibly as an interactive shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right; I'll update that in my answer; I got tripped up by the visual similarity to this exiting but leaving the processes forked hanging in the background, which isn't the case.

Comment: thanks for reply ...Can i write this way system("bash - l", "-c", "echo Hello World!");

Comment: @Yog Easily tried by executing `perl -e 'system("bash -l", "-c", "echo HW!");print "\n\tDone!!\n";'` You'll find it doesn't run correctly in the fork. Also `-l` and `-c` seem to be exclusive so you can't just list it on it's own in there. It seems like maybe you want to have bash running but be using perl to filter the user's input or output to bash? There's a module that might help make that a little easier: https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run

Comment: @dlamblin Yes you are right .I wanted to see output on console after executing bash command in perl. I did not know about logout using -c as I am new to perl scripting.

Comment: But here problem is I did logout immediately but commands after bash should be execute in newly created bash instance and i am doing like that system("bash -l" "c'); other commands .....

Comment: @Yog I'm sorry but I've lost track of what you want to do overall. I think you want bash to start, but after you exit it, for it to stay as process and for the subsequent perl commands to affect it? This gets tricky and has limited benefits over just either writing a 100% bash script that does everything, or a perl script that does it all. Specifically though, what "it" is is not obvious to me.

Comment: @dlamblin ok sorry about that I failed to explain you properly, Ok let me try on more time.So I have a perl script and I wants to create bash instance and then I wants to execute other commands/statements after creating bash instance for eg: system("----");print "Done!"; etc and then I only wants to see output on my console what ever commands executed after creating bash instance.I hope you understood my question now?here the problem is I can not see any output on my console.

Comment: @you can refer this code :                                                               #i!/usr/bin/perl
system("bash -l");
print "Done 1!..";
print "Done...";